# Php script can be used to write the hadoop pig's UDF?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Php script can be used to write the hadoop pig's udf?
Hadoop pig support python and javascript to UDF.

Answer (score 1):

The only supported languages are Java, Python, Ruby, and JavaScript as of 0.10.0. It seems new languages are being added frequently (JavaScript and Ruby), but I doubt PHP will ever be considered.

http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/udf.html

Answer (score 1):

UDFs cannot be in PHP, but you can use pig's `stream x through y` construct to stream the data through any type of program, if that helps.